# CheckBox at the Margin Right of Layout XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to put a `Checkbox` in this XML Layout. I've try many times but I always get an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like the CheckBox at the Margin Right. So, example:

IMAGE MyApplication MyPackage CheckBox **AT THE MARGIN RIGHT**

Comment: First off, the default orientation for LinearLayout is vertical.  Unless you provide android:layout_orientation="horizontal" then the objects will vertically align.

Also, what error do you get?  Please post this so we know what we are trying to help with.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder: Actually, that's incorrect. It's exactly the opposite of what you're claiming. [Check the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). ;)

Comment: @MH.: Correct you are actually, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />



    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try like this giving layout_orientation to linear layout.

Comment: Where is the CheckBox?

Comment: and why not single relative layout